# Addition of Inequalities

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I've got an inequality addition question:

If $5 + 3x \lt 14$ and $-x \lt 1$, one can find a range for $x$ by solving each equation independently. However, why can I not add the equations? For example:

$$5 + 3x - x \lt 14 + 1$$

$$\Rightarrow \quad 5 + 2x \lt 15$$

$$\Rightarrow \quad2x \lt 10$$

$$\Rightarrow \quad x \lt 5$$

This is clearly wrong, because if I plug in 4 into the first equation, it doesn't work?

I think I am missing something rather silly, but some help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

From $5+3x < 14$ and $-x<1$, by adding them up, you have conclude those inequalities imply that $x<5$.  $x<5$ is necessarily true. But from $x<5$ alone, we can't conclude that $5+3x < 14$ and $-x<1$ hold.

You should simplify the first inequality as much as possible first to get an upper bound for $x$ and use the second inequality to get a lower bound for $x$.

Answer (score 0):

You need to align the **positive** $x$'s, so the second equation becomes $x\gt-1$, and now you can see that your addition involves the two different inequality symbols.

Solve for the first# equation: $x\lt3$, and now we can join the two: $-1\lt x\lt 3$.